# Nuxt: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Использую nuxt-buefy таблицу для вывода информации, полученной по api. Получилось сделать в Admin Nuxt Bulma, перенёс страницу на более новую версию Nuxt и там уже получаю ошибку по типу Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Абсолютно одинаковый код на 2ух разных версиях. На старой всё работает корректно. Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Пример таблицы:

```
<b-table
 :checked-rows.sync="checkedRows"
 :checkable="checkable"
 :loading="isLoading"
 :paginated="paginated"
 :per-page="perPage"
 :striped="true"
 :hoverable="true"
 default-sort="id"
 :data="clients">
  <template slot-scope="props">
   <b-table-column label="№" field="id" sortable> {{ props.row.id }} </b-table-column>        
  </template>
</b-table>
```

[image: Vue DevTools]
[image: Таблица]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b-table-column v-slot="props" label="№" field="id" sortable> {{ props.row.id }} </b-table-column>
```

Вместо `slot-scope="props"` в начале, использовал `v-slot="props"` для каждого столбца

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас в `webtools` приходит `props.row.id` но все равно есть ошибка попробуйте `v-if`

```
    <b-table-column v-if="props.row" label="№" field="id" sortable> 
{{ props.row.id }} 
</b-table-column>
```

Comment: Поправил вопрос, добавил скрин из Vue DevTools, где видно, что данные приходят. На старой версии всё так же

Comment: @ClutcherGG я понял сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: @ClutcherGG извините не увидел а куда вы хотите вывесть этот темплейт в b-table есть #cell(<key>) - для ячеек и #head() для заголовка но slot-scope="props" для чего?

Comment: @ClutcherGG можно добавить сркин таблицы?

Comment: Добавил скрин правильной таблицы и vue devtools

Comment: [В документации buefy используется v-slot](https://buefy.org/documentation/table/)

Comment: Извините думал это bootstrap-vue с buefy не работал ещё

Comment: Попробуйте v-slot="props" вместо slot-scope

Comment: Да, действительно, всё заработало) Огромное спасибо)